# Finding wheather the mysql query performed a update or insert

Tags: java, mysql

I've a query as follows...

```
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE (f1,f2,f3,f4) VALUES (1,2,3,4) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE f4=5;
```

That I've achieved through,

Creating a connection,statement & executing the query as follows

```
    statement.execute(query);
```

But, now I need to find whether the code had performed an INSERT or UPDATE ?

Can anyone help me with this??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know any specific built in function or work around.

But in my case I would have made it possible like this in an easy way

```
select count(*) as oldcount from MYTABLE;
```

perform your Query at this level

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (f1,f2,f3,f4) VALUES (1,2,3,4) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE f4=5;

select count(*) as newCount from MYTABLE;

retrive OLDCOUNT and NEW COUNT

if(oldcount != new count)
{
  //InsertPerformed
}

else
{
  //updateperformed
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion bro... But I don't want to use subsequent calls to DB. Because The above example uses, 3 calls to DB. I'll upload for a minimum of 2000 rows to a max of 100000 rows. So, I think It'll not be feasible(for my problem). Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You might use instead two statements: `executeUpdate` returns the number of rows affected. If that number is 0, then you have to perform an insert.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

 With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, and 2 if an existing row is updated.

Comment: Yes, but execute() method only returns a boolean: no information about what sridhar wants to know.

Comment: What if the query is the `DELETE` operation? Isn't it return 0 too? Because in the documentation, says the `executeUpdate()` method return [either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Yes, he also needs to switch from execute() to executeUpdate().